# NSAttributedString drop shadow is cropping on descenders

Tags: objective-c, ios6

I am using `NSMutableAttributedString` in iOS6 to apply kerning and drop shadows within a `UILabel` subclass. The attributes are being applied properly, however the drop shadow is cropping at at the left edge of the first character and the bottom of descenders ( lowercase p for example ).  The label itself has `clipsToBounds` disabled.

The code...

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[self text]];
NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString length]);

NSNumber *kern = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.75f];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSKernAttributeName value:kern range:range];

NSShadow *shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
[shadow setShadowBlurRadius:3.0f];
[shadow setShadowColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]];
[shadow setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 2.0f)];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSShadowAttributeName value:shadow range:range];

[self setAttributedText:attributedString];
```

Its barely noticeable, but once you see it, it's obvious. Have others encountered this bug and is there a work-around?

Comment: And the label is big enough to accomodate the drop shadow?  What happens when you make it bigger?

Comment: Adjusting the height of the label resolves the problem with the descenders.  Thanks!  However, it doesn't fix the left edge. The label alignment is set as NSTextAlignmentLeft.

Comment: Please post a screenshot.

Comment: I need to up my reputation to post an image, but what it would show is a hard line at the left egde and not a nice feathered drop shadow.  It is particularly noticeable on rounded characters such as "O"

Comment: Have you tried self.layer.masksToBounds = NO; ?